# Round prices in woocommerce without rounding the total tax at cart and checkout

Tags: woocommerce, rounding, hook-woocommerce

I have tried rounding prices with this function and it works fine on the entire site.

```
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'round_up_raw_woocommerce_price' );
function round_up_raw_woocommerce_price( $price ){
    return ceil( $price );
}
```

However, it also rounds the **total value of taxes** in the cart and checkout total. Consequently, the breakdown of the tax amount is incorrect from an accounting point of view.

For example, let's put a rounded order total of €195 with 23% tax included. Using this function it will be displayed that total includes €37 of taxes instead of €36.46, which would be correct.

So it is an incorrect value if e.g. you want to generate an invoice from the purchase order.

Is there a way to add an exception so that the **total taxes** are not rounded?

Comment: The filter hook `raw_woocommerce_price` is used by the `wc_price()` function, that is used to format most of all WooCommerce displayed prices, regardless of the price kind. So it's not possible to target some prices and not some others...